# Parsing C to Ocaml

Tags: c, parsing, gcc, ocaml, llvm

I would like to get the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) from a C code, into an OCaml value, so that I can further process the parsed code with a plain OCaml program.

I had in mind to use GCC, get the AST (in GIMPLE) with a hook, and convert the GIMPLE code to Ocaml.

But I wonder if there is another way, or if someone did something similar already. (I haven't found much actually on that...)

I don't want to resort to using CIL. It is an OCaml parser for C code, but it doesn't contain all optimizations that GCC has. (I especially need a deeper alias analysis than the one implemented in CIL).

Can LLVM be a good idea to look at? Already done maybe?

Any better idea?

Comment: Parsing != Optimization. The latter comes later.

Answer (score 9):

If your problem with CIL is the precision of the provided alias analysis, take a look at [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/). It is based on CIL but provides a [precise value analysis](http://frama-c.com/media/first_S_full.png) that works for pointers. The value analysis makes its results available inside a modular architecture.

Comment: Seconded : CIL and Frama-C are probably the best tools you may hope for, and Pascal Cuoq is one of the right people to ask.

Comment: But how about writing a parser for GIMPLE code, or even LLVM code?
I'd then peek at the code *after* all the optimizations for those compilers, and parse the AST into an OCaml value...
Is that so...unthinkable?

Comment: @Daz If you go that route, I would recommend LLVM. At least until a few years ago, when we made our own choices, GCC developers provided no guarantees about the stability of Gimple, and indeed it was changing from version to version. I am not sure what sort of magic you expect from intermediate language optimizations, but for the applications in Frama-C, traceability and normalization of the code are more important than optimizations (and even just these two are hard to have at the same time without the third one).

Comment: @Daz If that is what you are wanting, I don't think you want an AST so much as an instruction set in an intermediate language.  Many of the optimizations for some of these compilers actually operate on the intermediate language, not on the source AST (so they can be applied to multiple languages).  LLVM would meet your needs, I think, although you won't see the optimizations done by LLVM itself if you just look at the LLVM output of e.g. clang.

Answer (score 1):

An other option to parse C to Ocaml would be [FrontC](http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/FrontC/FrontC.3.4/). Its description says :

> FrontC is an OCAML library providing a C parser and lexer. The result is a syntactic tree easy to process with usual OCAML tree management.
>
> It provides support for ANSI C syntax, old-C K&R style syntax and the standard GNU CC attributes.
>
> It provides also a C pretty printer as an example of use.